# LARAVEL 8 - I cannot view images from the Storage folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

sorry but I would need help with a project and I would be really grateful if you would help me.
The problem is that i cannot view the images from `public/storage` in a blade page.
To display the images I wrote:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $category->image) }}" alt="">
```

To create the folder `public/storage` I used the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

[image: image of folder path]

I tried to delete and to recreate the folder but it still doesn't work

The path of images:

```
storage/app/public/images/
```

[image: image of folder path]

I'm so sorry for my english, I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: can you show the exact path of the images uploaded in storage folder

Comment: I edit the post, hope that's what you were asking. Again sorry, it's my first question in stackoverflow

Comment: path is proper.are you sure $category->image has value .for testing purpose hardcode path  instead od dynamic once

Comment: print  $category->image too for testing purpose. and try accessing image directly from browser

Comment: yes before I tested and the value is correct. The problem is that i can't access in the storage folder

Comment: yes i got it but your code and folder looks good.any way once you delete shortcut created  storage folder from public/ and run php artisan stoage:link again

Comment: the problem persists, in any case thanks for the help

Comment: strange issue .if you are in linux check once permission .since both storage and code looks good,what error you get when you accessing directly from browser  .try accessing one image in browser yourdomain/storage/images/1623598728.jpg

Comment: for the permission, I just checked and everything seems normal. For the error in the browser, don't show any error. It just doesn't show the picture. Now i'm checking in 'yourdomain/storage/images/1623598728.jpg' and get errore 404

Comment: okay.will see some other might help on that.without project debugging bit diffcult for me so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a `Linux` user, then sometimes you need to give permission additionally to make it accessible. If you create your `storage` folder by the command `php artisan storage:link` and the `storage` folder has been corrupted, then delete the generated folder from `public` on the root and generate the shortcut by running the command again. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: It is strongly advised never to use 777 as folder permissions for security reasons.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with your point. It might be done only for testing purpose on local server.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to generate the folder from root but don't work.

Comment: @SAhmedNaim it was a good suggestion to check folder permissions though! Found a more detailed post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel/37266353#37266353 - 755 for folders seems to be a good starting point. I guess it depends a bit on server configuration finally

Comment: @JoseSgariglia If you don't have `root` permission then add `sudo` on linux machine before running the artisan command. If the problem still exists, then please write in details about your problem.

Comment: The problem is when i want show the image from storage folder, it doesn't appear. I tried to write all path of image (without use any value) but still don't working. I tested and the problem is that i can't access in the storage folder, i don't why. The code seems correct. The static images on other folder in `public` show without problem

Comment: I think a solution, that is to create a function that move the image from the `public/storage/image` to `public/foldername` but also do it, i have the error that the path is incorrect.